# Implement kotlin copy function for properties declared in the class body

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible in kotlin to write a copy function for properties declared in the class body rather than the primary constructor?

```
data class Person(val name: String) {
var age: Int = 0
}
```

How can I write copy function for the age variable?

Comment: May be you can use secondary constructor or even primary constructor with default value, Otherwise maybe its not possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just move the variable into constructor with default value like :

```
data class Person(val name: String, var age: Int = 0) {
}
```

then you can use it like:

```
Person("Andy")
Person("Andy", 29)
```

and copy will work fine as well:

```
val person = Person("Andy")
person.copy(age = 42)
```

Comment: I was just curious about how to achieve the same in my case. Copy function will work fine in the way you mentioned but what if I don't want compiler to handle equals,hashcode and toString for me for some variable by default.